# JavaFX: Make dragged node visible

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I want to drag and drop nodes between flowpanes. I implemented the drag and drop in this way:

```
public class TouchTask extends BorderPane{

setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
            clipboardContent.putString(TASK_DRAG_KEY);
            dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);

            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

The drag and drop works fine, but the problem is, that the node is not moved during the drag and drop gesture. I wanted to implement this drag and drop so that the node has the same position as the mouse during the gesture.

I tried to implement this in the following way:

```
onMousePressedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // record the current mouse X and Y position on Node
            mousex = event.getSceneX();
            mousey = event.getSceneY();

            x = getLayoutX();
            y = getLayoutY();

             if (isMoveToFront()) {
                 toFront();
             }
        }
    });

onMouseDraggedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // Get the exact moved X and Y

            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - mousex;
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - mousey;

            x += offsetX;
            y += offsetY;

            double scaledX = x;
            double scaledY = y;

            setLayoutX(scaledX);
            setLayoutY(scaledY);

            // again set current Mouse x AND y position
            mousex = event.getSceneX();
            mousey = event.getSceneY();

            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

But with this solution, the node is only moved for like 3 pixel and then it stops.

Comment: Do you actually want to translate the origin node while dragging, or do you want to take a snapshot of the origin node and use a Java 8 [DragView](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/input/Dragboard.html#setDragView-javafx.scene.image.Image-)?

Comment: sorry, but i dont know what you mean with "translate the origin node".

Comment: By translate the origin node I mean actually move the node to be moved while dragging it using the node's [translate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty()) property.  With a DragView, you wouldn't do that, instead you would leave the node where it is, create an image to represent it, then drag that image, only relocating the original node once the drag is successfully complete.

Comment: Oh ok i understand that. No i dont want to take a snapshot and leave the node where it is. The original node should be moved while the dragging.